# Android grid of dots to fill View

Tags: android, kotlin, game-development

I'm trying to make a game in Android Studio using Kotlin, currently I have a grid drawn using two for loops (1 for cols and 1 for rows) that draws dots. I want the dots to fill the View, without the blank space around the grid. Any ideas?

```
val columns = 5
val rows = 5 

var xPos: Float = width / (columns + 1)
var yPos: Float = height / (rows + 1)

        for (col in 1..columns) {
            for (row in 1..rows) {
                canvas.drawPoint(col*xPos, row*yPos, paint)
             }
         }
```

What I get:
 [image: What I get]
    d

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a little space around the edges. So you can have a variable for padding, which should be half the diameter of your dots plus however many pixels of white you want around them. You would probably calculate the size using a constant DIP unit and the screen density, same as you probably did for your paint to get the dot diameter.

Then you can use the padding in your calculation. For example, if you have five columns, to get the space between dots, you want to divide the width by four, after subtracting the padding from both sides.

```
val padding = /* ... */
val columns = 5
val rows = 5 
val hSpacing = (width - (2 * padding)) / (columns - 1)
val vSpacing = (height - (2 * padding)) / (rows - 1)

for (i in 0..columns)
    for (j in 0..rows)
        canvas.drawPoint(padding + i * hSpacing, padding + j * vSpacing, paint)
```

Comment: Note, I had rows and columns swapped in the spacing calculations.